# regex won't return string between html tags

Tags: html, regex

I've been pulling my hair out because of this: I'm trying to extract the text which is contained in the Loaction block of the code at the bottom. I'm looking to extract this:

`<h3 class="blue">Location</h3><p class="desc">This elegant luxurious hotel is located in the middle of stunning greenery on a hill, overlooking the sand/ pebble beach of Ixia, which is accessed just over the promenade (around 200 m away). The glamorous building, which is based on architecture from the Middle Ages is stylish and designed in classical, elegant decor. The island's capital of Rhodes Town is located around 4 km from the hotel and Rhodes' airport is roughly 9 km away whilst public transport departs from a stop located just 200 m away.</p>`

with

```
<h3 class="blue">Location<\/h3><p\s(.*)\s.<\/p>
```

but it won't work. Please can someone help. Regards

```
 ...In addition, there is also playground for younger guests in the hotel grounds.</p><h3 class="blue">Location</h3><p class="desc">This elegant luxurious hotel is located in the middle of stunning greenery on a hill, overlooking the sand/ pebble beach of Ixia, which is accessed just over the promenade (around 200 m away). The glamorous building, which is based on architecture from the Middle Ages is stylish and designed in classical, elegant decor. The island's capital of Rhodes Town is located around 4 km from the hotel and Rhodes' airport is roughly 9 km away whilst public transport departs from a stop located just 200 m away.</p><h3 class="blue">Rooms</h3><p class="desc">The comfortable rooms include an en suite bathroom with hairdryer, bathrobe, slippers, a direct dial telephone, satellite/ cable TV, a minibar, air conditioning (centrally regulated), a hire safe as well as a terrace or balcony.</p><h3 class="blue">Sports</h3><p class="desc">In the outdoor complex are 2 swimming pools with children's pools, a...
```

Comment: as in, I'm trying this on rubular.com and it just says no matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your language of choice has a library to parse HTML you ought to make use of it. Regex isn't always the best tool, but if you're familiar with the input it's possible to pull it off.

That said, your pattern is greedy, therefore it will match beyond the first ending paragraph tag. To make it non-greedy you need to use `.*?` (notice the addition of the `?`).

In addition, there's usually no need to escape the forward slash (but I guess you're using PHP, based on your history), and the use of `\s.` will cause your match to fail since the text doesn't end with a space followed by a character. The `.` is metacharacter that will match any character. If you meant to match a period you need to escape it to make it literal, as in `\.`.

I prefer to use `\b` to indicate a word boundary, instead of using `\s` after the `p` tag. Lastly, unless you wanted to capture the paragraph text, there's no need to use a capturing group `(.*?)`. Addressing all these issues leaves you with this:

```
<h3 class=\"blue\">Location<\/h3><p\b.*?<\/p>
```

If you want to capture the paragraph text, you could take this approach:

```
<h3 class=\"blue\">Location<\/h3><p[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>
```

- `[^>]*` match any character that is not a greater than symbol, zero or more times. Note the benefit of this portion of the pattern is that it's also non-greedy since matching stops as soon as a greater than symbol is encountered.
- `>` match a literal greater than symbol
- `(.*?)` capturing group for the inner paragraph content

Answer (score 0):

The end of your regex has `\s.<\/p>`. The end of your paragraph has `ay.</p>`. The `\s` matches a whitespace character, but your input has a `y` there and the match fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `\s` after the first group. You have no space before any dot in your string.

```
<h3 class="blue">Location<\/h3><p\s(.*).<\/p>
```